# How to create this grid layout with css?

Tags: html, css

How can I create this kind of design with css?
[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D2Zb.jpg) 
I try bento box but no luck.
Or
Please link the website that use this kind of design. I searched but I can't find any website. I find only figma or image

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: Be aware though that it's not possible to make non-rectangular elements.

Comment: True but this design, while tricky, is still possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no clean way of doing it.

The hack I’m demonstrating in this snippet uses a grid, but note that what appears to be a single orange element is actually two separate elements. So depending on the content you want to put inside, this implementation may or may not be suitable.

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
}

.d1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 0.5em auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto 0.5em auto;
}

.d1>* {
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

.d1>*:nth-child(1) {
  background: orange;
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 1;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.d1>*:nth-child(2) {
  background: orange;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-top: 1px dashed rgb(255 255 255 / 0.5);
}

.d1>*:nth-child(3) {
  background: orange;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.d1>*:nth-child(3)>* {
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 1.3em 0 0 0;
}

.d1>*:nth-child(4) {
  background: blue;
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div><div></div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```